# Laravel middleware redirecting from dashboard to login page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have written simple code for login but when I

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
            //dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
 }
```

(when I dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check()) in this I get **true** on login page but when I check that on dashboard I get **false** in `Auth::guard('admin')->check()`

```
    public function __construct()
    {    
      $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
      return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
```

I don't know why the session is being destroyed after redirecting to dashboard controller.

Please let me know any other inputs you want from my side.

Comment: Can u show me config/auth.php file

Comment: ` 'guards' => [
             'admin' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'admins',
          ],
         'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'usersWeb',
        ],
         'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],`

Comment: 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'usersWeb' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\UserWeb::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],

Comment: did you set route name _admin.dashboard_ in web.php file for admin dashboard page?

Comment: yes i have added that name